# How to split the string using python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to split the string using regex

```
input :
result = '1,000.03AM2,97.2323,089.301,903.230.0034,928.9911,24.30AM'
```

Want to split this so that I can store into different strings for further use like following

```
o/p should be :
a = 1,000.03AM, b = 2,97.23, c = 23,089.30, d = 1,903.23, e = 0.00, f = 34,928.99, g = 11,24.30AM
```

I have tried like this but it's showing wrong output

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[0-9.]+|[^0-9.]', result))
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed yes. Edited

Comment: What can be the max length of the string?

Comment: What is `AM` stands for? AM/PM? It looks like what you should parse it as float, but including AM/PM would make it string, unless it `time`.

Comment: @Abhi Your expected result is not matching with the above regex mentioned by Wiktor.

Comment: @shaikmoeed But my answer contains the solution that matches what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extract the strings using

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{2})?[^,\d]*', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KOh8VY/5)

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of a comma and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{2})?` - an optional occurrence of a dot and 2 digits
- `[^,\d]*` - any 0 or more chars other than a comma and digit.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/G3awND):

```
import re
text = "1,000.03AM2,97.2323,089.301,903.230.0034,928.9911,24.30AM"
print( re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{2})?[^,\d]*', text) )
# => ['1,000.03AM', '2,97.23', '23,089.30', '1,903.23', '0.00', '34,928.99', '11,24.30AM']
```

Comment: This gives the first element as `'1,000.03AM2'` where it should be `'1,000.03AM'` as mentioned by OP.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I have reverted to the original suggestion.

Comment: But still is not matching with expected output of OP.

Comment: After `.` there should only two digits(plus two alphabets if exists). But this results as `928.9911`

Comment: Ok, now it does.

Comment: @shaikmoeed See Python demo.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Thanks. Actually due to edits I was in confusion about actual output.:)

Answer (score 2):

For your result you need following regex:

```py
re.findall(r"[\d,]+\.\d{2}(?:AM)?", result)
```

This produce following:

```py
['1,000.03AM', '2,97.23', '23,089.30', '1,903.23', '0.00', '34,928.99', '11,24.30AM']
```

Regex explanation:

- `[\d,]` - match digits and comma
- `[\d,]+\.\d{2}` - match whole float value (with two digest after dot)
- `(?:AM)?` - matching optional `AM` in non-capturing group, in example below I use `(?=AM)?` to not include it into result
- In case on the place of `AM` you have anything else, you may edit `(?:AM)` to `(?:AM|Other|...)`

If you need to parse it as float, I have two suggestion for you. First is removing comma:

```py
map(lambda x: float(x.replace(",", "")), re.findall(r"[\d,]+\.\d{2}(?=AM)?", s))
```

Result:

```py
[1000.03, 297.23, 23089.3, 1903.23, 0.0, 34928.99, 1124.3]
```

Another variant is using `locale`:

```py
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')
'en_US.UTF8'
>>> list(map(lambda x: locale.atof(x), re.findall(r"[\d,]+\.\d{2}(?=AM)?", s)))
[1000.03, 297.23, 23089.3, 1903.23, 0.0, 34928.99, 1124.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided if string length and its parameter remains same.
Most efficient solution would be.

```
a = result[0:10]
b = result[10:17]
c = result[17:26]
d = result[26:34]
e = result[34:38]
f = result[38:47]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect the `AM` optional part may be missing or present in arbitrary comma-separated fields, so this is not likely to help in the end.

Comment: If alphabetical characters aren't important then you can try this re.findall(r"[\d,]+\.\d{2}", result)

Comment: This would be perfect.
re.findall(r"([\d,]+\.\d{2}[A-Z]{2}?|[\d,]+\.\d{2})", result)